# How to use the jquery .load() function to return the innerHTML of an element

Tags: jquery, load

**JQuery**

Assume this works: `$('table td').load('/my/url/ div p');`

I would end up with `<td><p>Some Text</p></td>`

I want to end up with `<td>Some Text</td>`

How would I do that?

Answer (score 9):

Select all immediate children of the p:

```
$('table td').load('/my/url/ div p > *');
```

Comment: Tried `div p *` and it was a disaster. Your solution worked tho :) +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a callback function.  Something like:

```
$('table td').load('/my/url/ div p', function () {
    $(this).find("p").replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: This wont't work due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX. By the time your second line is executed the DOM might not have been updated yet.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: I realized that after posting and quickly changed it to use the callback instead.  It was late and my brain was fried ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = $('table td').load('/my/url/ div p', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.find('p').html());
});
```